# Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable

Tags: corda

I am trying to handcraft a Node folder with following contents - Corda.jar (1.4), Node.conf, cordapp (Folder).

Receiving following error on Node startup (java -jar ./Corda.jar)

```
Logs can be found in                    : 
! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.

[ERROR] 15:20:24-0400 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Couldn't find network parameters file and compatibility zone wasn't configured/isn't reachable. [errorCode=1917kd6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/1917kd6]
```

Following are the contents of Node.conf file :

```
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress="localhost:10014"
rpcSettings {
    address="localhost:10015"
    adminAddress="localhost:10016"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test1
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Expected : Node starts

Actual : Exception (above)

Comment: When you hand-craft a node you need a few more things. You need to either specify a Corda network to join in the node.conf and put the network root truststore in the certificates folder and then run corda with `initial-registration`. This isn't necessary if you just want to stand up a network locally, in that case you can use the `cordform` task as described [here](https://docs.corda.net/generating-a-node.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Florian mentioned, you can use the corda network bootstrapper to create a local run-able Corda environment.

Feel free to flow the guide here: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-bootstrapper.html

The issue with handcraft the node folders yourself is that you will run into very complicated process of certificates, network parameters, and etc.